# Cannot get reference to ListView via function called by webmethod

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-ajax, webmethod

I am trying to reference my ListView control to assign a datasource to it. But oddly, it is 'Nothing' when I debug 'Me.lvResults' What could be causing this? I am leaning toward the  Method calling the BindDataSearch() function that is part of the class Default. I really need the code to work like this because I ajax call Search(), but if anyone can recommend a better way I am open to suggestions. Thank you very much for your time,

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class _Default
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   End Sub


   <WebMethod()>
   Public Shared Sub Search(ByVal StartDate As String, ByVal EndDate As String, ByVal ClassName As String)
    Try
        'Get Search Results
        Dim _DataHelper As New DataHelper
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt = _DataHelper.ClassSearch(StartDate, EndDate, ClassName)

        'Bind Search Results to DateGrid
        Dim _ClassSearch As New _Default
        _ClassSearch.BindDataSearch(dt)
     Catch ex As Exception
        Dim strError As String = ex.ToString()
     End Try
    End Sub


    Public Sub BindDataSearch(ByVal dt As DataTable)
     Me.lvResults.DataSource = dt
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. This is a *shared* method, meaning there is no instance of the page when the method is called.

You may want to look into the method passing the data back to the page using JSON and then using JQuery to create the object on the client-side. But there is no way to do Databinding using a WebMethod.